# Functional state management and large array datasets

Tags: redux, functional-programming, state, reactive-programming

I'm looking to apply the paradigms from my experience in using Redux for state management in web applications into an iOS app that will be written in Swift. The reason full native is being chosen is in part due to the requirement of handling large datasets on the device and needing to render UIs around these large datasets (specifically, looking at large polygons to be rendered on a map - our worst case so far is 24 000 points in memory, and an optimisation of that for rendering on screen).

Given that a functional state management system should not be mutating the existing state, what options are there to limit the overhead for dealing with large datasets that have a cost for deep copying?

While I have some ideas about potentially modifying our data structure away from vectors of numbers to vectors of indexable/id-able structures that can be operated on more granularly, there still remains the issue (as I can see) that at least one large copy operation per array, per update would need to happen.

Are there sensible ways of dealing with this issue in a way that stays true to the idea that you never mutate the state directly?

Comment: Regarding deep copying: Functional data structures are often recursive and contain a natural form of structural sharing. When you prepend a node to a list, for instance, you reuse the previous one. When you modify a rose tree with a zipper or lens, only the respective subtree is actually copied and modified. I think immutable.js implements  persistent ordered/unodered `Map`/`Set` structures using hash tries - look at this in more detail.

Comment: @ftor But if you don't/can't have access to 3rd party language structures which optimise the immutable data copy process, is not the problem still present? I'm looking at implementations of this structure in both Swift and C++ so the Immutable lib would likely have cousins in both languages, but depending on project management choices they may not be able to be added.